# dart-define return empty string vscode Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

If I define the run configuration as follow, as reported in the documentation [here](https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/) when I try to get variable value from code it is always empty.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "appname (DEV)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
            "console": "debugConsole",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "--flavor", 
                "dev"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "toolArgs": [
                "--dart-define",
                "FIREBASE_ANDROID_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxx",
                "--dart-define",
                "FIREBASE_IOS_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx",
                "--dart-define",
                "EAS_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx",
                "--dart-define",
                "EAS_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxx",
                "--dart-define",
                "SIGNING_CERTIFICATE_HASH=xxxxxxxxxx",
                "--dart-define",
                "DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
        },
]
```

if from code I do this:

```
String.fromEnvironment('DB_PASSWORD')
```

it returns

```
""
```

but I expect that the value is the value in the configuration

Comment: Are you sure that you are running it with the configuration file you created in the run and debug section ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I know it's weird

Comment: Can you put in the comment line this part and try again 
'''
 "args": [
                "--flavor", 
                "dev"
            ],
'''

Answer (score 2):

Add `const` :

```
const String.fromEnvironment('DB_PASSWORD')
```

When running from Flutter, these strings only appear to work when constant (see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870)). There's a request for a warning about this [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42177).

Comment: I wish *I* could choose this as the accepted answer. This works.